# Magento 2 link of store->configurations->customer tab inside adminhtml phtml template file

Tags: magento2.4.1

I have an adminhtml phtml file. I want to add a link of page inside store->configurations->customer tab. I have "Add Secret Key to URLs" enabled. I have added this code to my phtml file

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('admin/system_config/edit/section/order_history_promotions', 
['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true, '_query' => $prams]); ?>" >
    Configuration Link 
 </a>
```

Now when i click on this link, this link is not opening due to invalid URL key attached to it.

This is my system.xml content.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="customer" translate="label" sortOrder="201">
            <label>Customer</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="order_history_promotions" translate="label" sortOrder="500" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Order History Promotions</label>
            <tab>customer</tab>
            <resource>Marketplace_PricePromotions::pricepromotions_config</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Promotions based on order history</label>
                <field id="apply" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Apply</label>
                    <source_model>Marketplace\PricePromotions\Model\Config\Source\ListMode</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="discount_amount" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Discount Amount</label>
                    <comment>Dicount amount like 20, 80 or 500 etc</comment>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it another way. Instead of opening the page, i have added configuration page url directly to this new link using etc/adminhtml/menu.xml
like this.

see **action="admin/system_config/edit/section/order_history_promotions"**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Marketplace_PricePromotions::pricepromotions_config" 
        title="Order History Promotions" module="Marketplace_PricePromotions" sortOrder="100" 
        parent="Magento_CatalogRule::promo" action="admin/system_config/edit/section/order_history_promotions" 
         resource="Marketplace_PricePromotions::pricepromotions_config"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```